# Check if map is endomorphism and compute its kernel in GAP

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, gap

I have to solve the following problem with GAP:

> Given R = $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^5+x^4+1)$, I have to compute the kernel of $f:R \to R$ given by $f(p)=p^2-p$.

To do that I would like to know if  *f*  is an homomorphism.

- Is there some function in GAP to solve this?
- How can I compute if this is an homomorfisms?

**What I did:**
If it were a field it would be great because the Frobenius Endomorfism is well understood, but this is not a field since $x^5+x^4+1$ is not irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$.

On the other hand, I programmed the following:

```
x:=Indeterminate(ZmodnZ(2),"x");
modulo:=x^5+x^4+1;
P:=PolynomialRing(ZmodnZ(2),"x");
R:=P/Ideal(P,[modulo]);
nucleo:=Filtered(Elements(R), x->x^2=x);
```

which give that the kernel is:
`[ 0*(1), (x2)+(x3)+(x4), (1), (1)+(x2)+(x3)+(x4) ]`

- Is the code above correct to solve the problem?

Comment: Homomorphism, not "homomorfism", and Frobenius, not "Frobenious". You can consider each irreducible factor of $x^5+x^4+1$, there are two of them.

Comment: @DietrichBurde you meant Homomorphism, not "endomorphism"?

Comment: It might be easier to consider the map $p^2-p$
 on the whole polynomial ring and then to show that the kernel contains the given ideal. There is no turnkey function for this in GAP, but one could use polynomial arithmetic (remainders, or in the multivariate case Gr\"obner bases) for the actual calculations needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is correct for getting the result. It computes (in a brute-force way) the kernel, assuming the map is a homomorphism.
You migth want to observe that it is a 2-dimensional vector space.
To show that it is a homomorphism it probably is easiest to use a theoretical argument and show that the map is a homomorphism on $Z_2$ and extends to the full polynomial ring. (This will be easier, as the polynomial ring is a free cyclic algebra.)